# NSURLSessionWebSocketTask return Bad Address error

Tags: ios, websocket, nsurlsession

We receive bad address error

```
Error:（kNWErrorDomainPOSIX 错误 14 - Bad address）,未能完成该操作。
Translated:（kNWErrorDomainPOSIX error 14 - Bad address）,The Operation Can't Be Completed.
Environment: iPhone 8#iOS#13.6#
```

from completion handler in

```
-[NSURLSessionWebSocketTask receiveMessageWithCompletionHandler:]
```

or

```
-[NSURLSessionWebSocketTask sendMessage:completionHandler:]
```

I'm not quit sure which one since their reporting error from same function in our code :(

===================================================

I was search information about

```
#define EFAULT          14              /* Bad address */
```

and socket,  most of content telling me that we did not pass buffer to socket function properly. But NSURLSessionWebSocketTask has no method for me to manipulate underlying socket.

===================================================

We can not reproduce this error since it was reported from user device. Any possible reason that make this error happen?